# Colors in the scatter plot with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I tried to write a function that will create a scatter plot in excel with openpyxl with automatic selection of colors. But it fails. I don't understand why the color codes not working. What does openpyxl exactly use. Documentation is opaque.

```
import openpyxl as pyxl
from openpyxl.chart import ScatterChart, Reference, Series
from openpyxl.chart.marker import Marker
from matplotlib.colors import cnames


def insert_scatter_chart_with_markers(ws=None, data_start_cell=None, data_end_cell=None, chart_position=None, chart_size=(15, 7.5), title="Chart", style=1):
    """
    Insert a scatter plot with markers into an existing Excel file.

    :param data_start_cell: Top-left cell of the DataFrame data range (e.g., 'A2').
    :param data_end_cell: Bottom-right cell of the DataFrame data range (e.g., 'C10').
    :param chart_position: Position to place the top-left corner of the chart (e.g., 'D2').
    :param chart_size: Tuple of (width, height) for the chart size.
    """

    # Create a scatter chart
    chart = ScatterChart()
    chart.title = title
    chart.style = style
    chart.x_axis.title = 'Date'
    chart.y_axis.title = 'Value'
    chart.width, chart.height = chart_size

    # Calculate the data range for the x-axis (DateTimeIndex) and y-values
    if isinstance(data_start_cell, str):
        min_row, min_col = pyxl.utils.cell.coordinate_to_tuple(data_start_cell)
    else:
        min_row, min_col = data_start_cell
    
    if isinstance(data_end_cell, str):
        max_row, max_col = pyxl.utils.cell.coordinate_to_tuple(data_end_cell)
    else:
        max_row, max_col = data_end_cell

    if isinstance(chart_position, tuple):  
        chart_position = pyxl.utils.get_column_letter(chart_position[0]) + str(chart_position[1])

    excel_default_colors = [
        'blue',
        'orange',
        'gray',
        'darkblue',
        'darkorange',
        'green',
        'lightblue',
        'gold',
        'lightgray',
        'darkred',
        'lightgreen',
        'brown',
        'darkgreen',
        # You can add more color names as needed
    ]
    

    # Add data series to the chart
    for i in range(min_col + 1, max_col + 1):
        color = excel_default_colors[i % len(excel_default_colors)]
        color = cnames[color].replace('#', 'FF')
        x_values = Reference(ws, min_col=min_col, min_row=min_row+1, max_row=max_row)
        y_values = Reference(ws, min_col=i, min_row=min_row, max_row=max_row)
        series = Series(y_values, x_values, title_from_data=True)
        series.marker = Marker(symbol='circle')
        series.marker.graphicalProperties.solidFill = color # Set the marker color
        series.marker.graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = color
        series.graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = color # Set the line color
        chart.series.append(series)

    # Add the chart to the worksheet
    ws.add_chart(chart, chart_position)



import openpyxl as pyxl
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

file = os.path.join('test.xlsx')
x = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,10, (10, 5)))
x.to_excel(file)


wb = pyxl.load_workbook(file)
ws = wb['Sheet1']

insert_scatter_chart_with_markers(ws, 'A1', 'C9', title='test', chart_size=(30, 10), chart_position=(1, 10), style=13)

wb.save(file)
```

Expected a standard colored excel color scatter plot. Nothing fancy.

Comment: I would change the line `color = cnames[color].replace('#', 'FF')` to  `color = cnames[color].replace('#', '')'` and the chart should be produced without error. The line and markers will have the same colour so if you need/want these to be different you might want to set the markers to black ('000000') while the chart lines are selected from your colour list.